# Is there a way to import a rules file from outside the classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, kie

I'm messing around with Drools decision tables in eclipse and noticed that the only way I've been able to import a rules file into my Kie session involves placing the file directly in the eclipse project. I was wondering if there was a way to access a rules file located somewhere in "C:Users/user/documents/rules/" or if the file had to be in the workspace.

I'm not super familiar with Drools or KIE so the only knowledge of the services that I have involve the documentation on the website and the various tutorials across google and youtube. The code that I've found so far doesn't seem to be enough.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-dtables");
```

The above directly references a session pre-defined in an xml file and I'm not sure how to define my own to access a file outside the eclipse project.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
Resource dt 
     = ResourceFactory
          .newClassPathResource("Sample.xls", getClass());

KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem().write(dt);
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
kieBuilder.buildAll();
KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
ReleaseId krDefaultReleaseId = kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(krDefaultReleaseId);
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

And this block was slightly better because I can directly reference one file in the project, but the problem is that it still needs to be within the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth I was able to find a work around.

Drools has a library that tries to convert any excel decision table file into a DRL file. Using this library, I used my excel file's path and then essentially converted the DRL into a string to then add to the KIE session. It ended up looking something like this:

```
import org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler;

String rulesExcel = "C:\\my\\path\\file.xls";
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is= new FileInputStream(rulesExcel);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
SpreadsheetCompiler sc = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
String rules=sc.compile(is, InputType.XLS);
KieSession kieSession = new KieHelper().addContent(rules, ResourceType.DRL).build().newKieSession();
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly, but do you know why "new KieHelper().addContent(rules, ResourceType.DRL).build()", takes so much time ? about 30 secs. thanks